# Server received all data but HttpSendRequest return FALSE 12002 in client

Tags: c++, sockets, http, winapi, http-headers

The Client sends some data to Server via `HttpSendRequest`:

```
            if (!HttpSendRequest(request.get(), NULL, 0,
                     const_cast<char *>(request_body.data()),
                     static_cast<DWORD>(request_body.size()))) {
                // return false;
            }
```

My Server received all data in `request_body` then send response:

```
            char success_message[] =
                    "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" "\n"
                    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" "\n"
                    "Content-Length: 0" "\n";
```

(I send this response via socket)
but in client `HttpSendRequest` block ~10 seconds then return `FALSE` with error `12002` return from `GetLastError().`

So my question is:

1. Is my reponse message in wrong format?
2. When `HttpSendRequest` return from blocking?

Edit 1:
this is the request from client, there are more data but not need, i though

```
    POST / HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------0000002900004823
    User-Agent: Breakpad/1.0 (Windows)
    Host: 127.0.0.1:1519
    Content-Length: 437805
    Cache-Control: no-cache

    -----------------------------0000002900004823
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="channel"


    -----------------------------0000002900004823
```

Comment: You need to read more about the [HyperText Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), because that response is not a correct one. It times out because you haven't terminated the header correctly.

Comment: Error 12002 means the server timed out, you need to make sure that there is no infinite loop in the code on the server side, or maybe dealing with too big data.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks, how could i create a correct header? I only wanna tell client status 200 OK

Comment: @Miche: I'm sure that i done in processing request and sent above response message

Comment: First of all, all line endings should be `"\r\n"`, then the header stops with a blank line. ***Read*** the HTTP specification!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks, i try the message at link you give me, it's good, but i still see something wrong, now i have to go home, i post here later, once again thank you very much!

Comment: Do you actually support the HTTP 1.1 specification? I don't see a `Connection: close` header in there. Are you sure you don't need one? Was the request an HTTP 1.1 request? Do you want to send an HTTP 1.1 reply to an HTTP 1.0 request?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: `Connection: close` is optional in HTTP 1.1. If not present, `Connection: keep-alive` is assumed. If the client actually requests `Connection: close` then the server must return `Connection: close` as well.  So in that regard, yes, he needs to analyze the request and format the response accordingly.  But that is a separate issue from the one being asked here, it warrants a separate question if needed.  This question has been answered (fix the line breaks).

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's the same issue -- he claims HTTP 1.1 compliance but doesn't follow the protocol's requirements. If he's going to claim HTTP 1.1 compliance, he needs to follow everything the protocol requires. (He could return an HTTP 1.0 reply.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: my server is an win32 application wrote in c++, not a web server like xampp, so my server don't fully support HTTP 1.1, i just accept socket, then receive data and process them, but i need to tell the client that i receive successfully. Thank you, i'm newbie in HTTP :(

Comment: @user1730500 This will lead to lots and lots of pain. Either support HTTP 1.1 or don't claim to support HTTP 1.1, but not supporting a protocol while claiming to support it is not a good idea.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I know what you mean, but my server is only need to receive above-formated-data, but in client use HttpSendRequest to send data, so i need to send some formated-respond-data for that HttpSendRequest can return true, then HttpQueryInfo can get the status code (200, 400, ...)

Comment: So then why claim support for HTTP 1.1?

Comment: because i must not change client source :(

Comment: You don't need to change the client.  Simply change your server to send an HTTP 1.0 reply instead of an HTTP 1.1 reply.  An HTTP 1.1 client can receive an HTTP 1.0 reply, but an HTTP 1.0 client cannot receive an HTTP 1.1 reply.  The version of the reply must never be greater than the version of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client is timing out because your server is not sending a well-formed response.  Read the HTTP specification, [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), in particular [Section 4 HTTP Message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4) and [Section 6 Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6) for syntax rules.

Try this:

```
char success_message[] =
                "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" "\r\n"
                "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" "\r\n"
                "Content-Length: 0" "\r\n"
                "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm precious. Now i'm not in my company, i will try it later.